# Get a list of customer who don't shop in a certain shop

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe of transactions and customers:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'shop': pd.Series(['McDonalds', 'McDonalds', 'McDonalds', 'McDonalds', 'Burger King', 'Burger King', 'Burger King', 'Burger King', 'Burger King', 'Trump Golf Course', 'Trump Golf Course', 'Trump Golf Course', 'Trump Golf Course', 'Trump Golf Course', 'Trump Golf Course'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)), 'Customer': pd.Series(['John Ryan', 'Jim Bob', 'Mary Ryan', 'Michael Patric', 'John Ryan', 'Jim Bob', 'Mary Ryan', 'Sean Connery', 'Brad Pitt', 'John Ryan', 'John Ryan', 'Michael Patric', 'Mary Ryan', 'John Ryan', 'Jim Bob'],dtype='object',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)), 'Customer ID': pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1)), 'Amount': pd.Series([50, 32, 15, 65, 32, 51, 54, 84, 52, 51, 2, 32, 54, 87, 65],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=15, step=1))

print(df)

                 shop        Customer  Customer ID  Amount
0           McDonalds       John Ryan            1      50
1           McDonalds         Jim Bob            2      32
2           McDonalds       Mary Ryan            3      15
3           McDonalds  Michael Patric            4      65
4         Burger King       John Ryan            1      32
5         Burger King         Jim Bob            2      51
6         Burger King       Mary Ryan            3      54
7         Burger King    Sean Connery            5      84
8         Burger King       Brad Pitt            6      52
9   Trump Golf Course       John Ryan            1      51
10  Trump Golf Course       John Ryan            1       2
11  Trump Golf Course  Michael Patric            4      32
12  Trump Golf Course       Mary Ryan            3      54
13  Trump Golf Course       John Ryan            1      87
14  Trump Golf Course         Jim Bob            2      65
```

I want to extract or tag the Burger King customers who haven't shopped in McDonalds. (In this case, Sean Connery and Brad Pitt)

I'm trying to create a mask where the `shop == McDonalds`, and get the customer ID

```
mask1 = df.shop == 'McDonalds'

mcdonalds_customer_ids = df[mask1]['Customer ID'].values

array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Then create a separate mask, where `shop=='Burger King'` and the customer ID is not in the list of McDonalds customer IDs:

```
mask = (df['shop'] == 'Burger King' & df['Customer ID'] not in mcdonalds_customer_ids)
```

I'm getting the below errors:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [int64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

I have tried using `np.where` also, but it became even messier.

My expected output is simply to extract the two Burger King customers who haven't shopped in McDonalds:

```
                 shop        Customer  Customer ID  Amount
7         Burger King    Sean Connery            5      84
8         Burger King       Brad Pitt            6      52
```

Or to tag them using np.where:

```
                 shop        Customer  Customer ID  Amount  No_McDonalds
7         Burger King    Sean Connery            5      84  True
8         Burger King       Brad Pitt            6      52  True
```

I can do this with a function, but was hoping to vectorize it somehow. Total fail, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).
First we get the rows of `Burger King`, then we get the `Customers` from `McDonalds`

And finally check which customer from `Burger King` have *not* been to `McDonalds`:

```
bk = df.loc[df['shop'].eq('Burger King')]
mc = df.loc[df['shop'].eq('McDonalds'), 'Customer']

bk[~bk['Customer'].isin(mc)]

          shop      Customer  Customer ID  Amount
7  Burger King  Sean Connery            5      84
8  Burger King     Brad Pitt            6      52
```

Comment: Essentially the same logic as mine but so much cleaner!

Comment: Is `.eq` the same as `==`? I've never used it before.

Comment: Yes the functionality is, plus you can specify some extra arguments like `fill_value`, furthermore I find it cleaner in my code, but that's preference. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) @SCool

Answer (score 2):

In your case, *I want to extract or tag the Burger King customers who haven't shopped in McDonalds*, you can just do:

```
s = (set(df.loc[df.shop.eq('Burger King'), 'Customer ID']) 
    - set(df.loc[df.shop.eq('McDonalds'), 'Customer ID'])
    )
```

Output `s`:

```
{5, 6}
```

And to extract those customer records with `Buger King`:

```
df[df.shop.eq('Burger King') & df['Customer ID'].isin(s)]
```

Output:

```
          shop      Customer  Customer ID  Amount
7  Burger King  Sean Connery            5      84
8  Burger King     Brad Pitt            6      52
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
aux = df.groupby('Customer').shop.sum()

df['No_McDonalds'] = df.Customer.map(aux.apply(lambda x: ('Burger King' in x) & ('McDonalds' not in x)))
```

### Output:

```
                 shop        Customer  Customer ID  Amount  No_McDonalds
0           McDonalds       John Ryan            1      50         False
1           McDonalds         Jim Bob            2      32         False
2           McDonalds       Mary Ryan            3      15         False
3           McDonalds  Michael Patric            4      65         False
4         Burger King       John Ryan            1      32         False
5         Burger King         Jim Bob            2      51         False
6         Burger King       Mary Ryan            3      54         False
7         Burger King    Sean Connery            5      84          True
8         Burger King       Brad Pitt            6      52          True
9   Trump Golf Course       John Ryan            1      51         False
10  Trump Golf Course       John Ryan            1       2         False
11  Trump Golf Course  Michael Patric            4      32         False
12  Trump Golf Course       Mary Ryan            3      54         False
13  Trump Golf Course       John Ryan            1      87         False
14  Trump Golf Course         Jim Bob            2      65         False
```

If you need some explanation please let me know and I'll help.

Answer (score 1):

A mix of groupby `transform`, `unique` and list comprehension

```
m = ['McDonalds' not in x for x in  df.groupby('Customer').shop.transform('unique')]

df[m]

Out[494]:
          shop      Customer  Customer ID  Amount
7  Burger King  Sean Connery  5            84
8  Burger King  Brad Pitt     6            52
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.loc[~df['Customer'].isin(df.where(df['shop'] == 'McDonalds')['Customer'].dropna().values) & df['shop'].eq('Burger King')]
```

Result:

```
          shop      Customer  Customer ID  Amount
7  Burger King  Sean Connery            5      84
8  Burger King     Brad Pitt            6      52
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using groupby like this

```py
result = df.groupby("Customer") \
.apply(lambda g: g.assign(No_McDonalds= (g["shop"]!="McDonalds").all())) \
.reset_index(drop=True)
```